# Add a character at the end of a string in the layout XML

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, textview, android-xml

I have this string resource:

```
<string name="trailer_duration">Duration</string>
```

In some cases I want to use this string resource as is and in another case I want to use the resource but add a ":" at the end of the string. I don't want to do this programmatically if there is a way to do it inside the XML file.

How can I achieve this inside the XML file?

This is the layout xml snippet:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/subtitle_title"
    style="@style/TrailerPlayerTrailerSubtitleTitle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:paddingRight="5dp"
    android:text="@string/trailer_subtitle" />
```

Comment: AFAIK You have to do it programmaticaly.

Comment: use dataBinding for achieve this.

Comment: That must be done programatically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this using data-binding. 
https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/index.html

```
android:text="@{user.displayName != null ? user.displayName : user.lastName}
```

but I think doing it programmatically (not in xml) is far easier than learning something new.